# Understanding a Sentence

Tags: word-difference

I have a problem understanding the following sentences.

> Some experiments suggest that deliberately releasing altered nonpathogenic *pseudomonas syringae* could crowd out the nonaltered variety that causes frost damage. Opponents of such research have objected that the deliberate and large-scale release of genetically altered bacteria might have deleterious results.

The experiments suggest that using altered bacteria could get rid of frost damage, which is a good result. So the opponent to this research should object the fact that "usage of altered bacteria makes good result". Then isn't it wrong to say that Opponents of the research objected that release of altered bacteria might have "**deleterious"** result? (In other words, shouldn't the word "deleterious" be changed to "good"? I am understanding the word "object" as a meaning of "oppose to".)

Comment: Why would someone object to **good** results?  People are objecting to the fact that the release *might* have *bad* results.  The paragraph just doesn't say what those bad results might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

There are two groups of people:

> Group 1 - wants to release genetically altered bacteria.
>   Group 2 - "opponents" do not want to release genetically altered bacteria.

The first sentence applies to Group 1. They want to release genetically altered bacteria because it will be good for preventing frost damage.

The second sentence applies to Group 2 and explains *why* they oppose it (think that this is *bad*) - because releasing genetically altered bacteria might have [deleterious](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deleterious) results. Group two is worried that, while there may be benefits to releasing the altered bacteria, they are concerned that there will be negative effects that are unpredicted.

The problem is that you're seeing it as a simple black/white argument and it's not. Group 2 isn't saying that it's "not good". They are saying that, while it may be *partially* beneficial, there are *potential* negative effects.

If it helps, think of the sentence this way:

> Opponents of such research have objected [to the usage, saying] that the deliberate and large-scale release of genetically altered bacteria might have deleterious results.

This is probably what is actually *meant* but we get away with removing it because it's a pretty common usage. It's a waste of space in an article to just say

> Person A thinks it's good but person B objects that it's good.

If someone objects, obviously they think it's bad for some reason, so we're going to tell you what that reason is.

In this case, it's the "[unintended consequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unintended_consequences#Unexpected_drawbacks)". There have been dozens of examples of non-native species being introduced into an ecosystem to have them control a native species... and then becoming a pest in their own right.

Comment: Isn't the word "object" means "oppose to"? The opponents are opposing to Group 1's opinion which is "release gene can make good results". So I thought that the sentence should be "Opponents object that  release of gene can make good results" which is same as "Opponents argue against the fact that release of gene can make good results". Am I understanding the word "object" in a wrong way?

Comment: I think you are interpreting "object" slightly wrong.  They're not opposing the opinion, they're just opposing the action.  That's why it says "opponents of such research", where *such research* means "deliberately releasing bacteria".